# Extract HTML content using YQL?

Tags: javascript, json, yahoo, yql

Let say I want to extract data from a web page with the following markup:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="Link 1">Column 1 Text</a></td>
    <td>Column 2 Text</td>
    <td>Column 3 Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="Link 2">Column 1 Text</a></td>
    <td>Column 2 Text</td>
    <td>Column 3 Text</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

to **JSON** format :

```
[
  {
    link: 'Link 1',
    text: 'Column 1 Text',
    data: 'Column 3 Text'
  },
  {
    link: 'Link 2',
    text: 'Column 1 Text',
    data: 'Column 3 Text'
  }
]
```

Can we make it with YQL? If yes then please give me an example query.

Any helps would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a query that's a good starting point, using the HTML table along with some XPath query (see [Extracting HTML Content With XPath](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-select-xpath.html) for more details on this technique):

[`select * from html where url="http://cantoni.org/test/table.html" and xpath='//table/tr'`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fcantoni.org%2Ftest%2Ftable.html%22%20and%20xpath%3D%27%2F%2Ftable%2Ftr%27)

Which produces JSON results like this:

```
{
 "query": {
  "count": 2,
  "created": "2012-01-06T20:16:46Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "results": {
   "tr": [
    {
     "td": [
      {
       "a": {
        "href": "Link%201",
        "content": "Column 1 Text"
       }
      },
      {
       "p": "Column 2 Text"
      },
      {
       "p": "Column 3 Text"
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "td": [
      {
       "a": {
        "href": "Link%202",
        "content": "Column 1 Text"
       }
      },
      {
       "p": "Column 2 Text"
      },
      {
       "p": "Column 3 Text"
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```