# YQL Terms of Use :html table is no longer supported

Tags: jquery

i am using YQL to get the content of html pages and it used to be working fine , but suddenly it s not the case ,this is what i get 
message : "html table is no longer supported. See https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/terms/product-atos/yql/index.htm for YQL Terms of Use" results : []

Comment: I don't have the faintest idea of what YQL looks like or is used for, but it's the first time I see a legal document attached to a deprecation notice. It's so enterprisey!

Comment: There's a discussion of this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431212/yql-html-table-is-no-longer-supported