# How can one get advanced notifications if components of YQL are being deprecated?

Tags: yql

I recently had a production service fail because YQL changed their policy and my html query stopped working. I was able to resolve it with the answer posted here: [YQL: html table is no longer supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431212/yql-html-table-is-no-longer-supported), but my question is, how would I get notified in advance if Yahoo decides to change it's policies again so that I am not scrambling for a solution. I wroite an email to 'yql-questions@yahoo-inc.com' over a week ago asking this question but received no response.