# YQL new htmlstring table not working like the old html table

Tags: javascript, yql

I've been using YQL for HTML scraping but now Yahoo have stopped supporting the html table so I replaced it with the htmlstring table (community table) and the additional parameters as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431212/yql-html-table-is-no-longer-supported).

However, I used to search for all divs and get them returned as an array so I could iterate through the elements, now when using htmlstring I get the result as plain HTML and I can't do anything with it.

Here's an example of how it looks now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/03LVp.jpg

I used to be able to loop through all divs in the array `query.results.div`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by cleaning up the html and using html2json.