# html table no longer supported

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest, tableau-api, yql

As others before I used `yql` to get data from a website. The website is in `xml` format.

I am doing this to build a web data connector in Tableau to connect to `xml`data and I got my code from here: https://github.com/tableau/webdataconnector/blob/v1.1.0/Examples/xmlConnector.html

As recommended on here: [YQL: html table is no longer supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431212/yql-html-table-is-no-longer-supported) I tried `htmlstring` and added the reference to the community environment.

```
 // try to use yql as a proxy
 function _yqlProxyAjaxRequest2(url, successCallback){
    var yqlQueryBase = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";
    var query = "select * from htmlstring where url='" + url + "'";
    var restOfQueryString = "&format=xml" ;
    var yqlUrl = yqlQueryBase + encodeURIComponent(query) + restOfQueryString + "&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
   _ajaxRequestHelper(url, successCallback, yqlUrl, _giveUpOnUrl9);
 }
 function _giveUpOnUrl9(url, successCallback) {
    tableau.abortWithError("Could not load url: " + url);
 }
```

However, I still got the message: Html table no longer supported.

As I don't know much about `yql`, I tried to work with `xmlHttpRequest`instead, but Tableau ended up processing the request for ages and nothing happened.

Here my attempt to find another solution and avoid the yql thingy:

```
 function _retrieveXmlData(retrieveDataCallback) {
  if (!window.cachedTableData) {
    var conData = JSON.parse(tableau.connectionData);
    var xmlString = conData.xmlString;
    if (conData.xmlUrl) {
      var successCallback = function(data) {
        window.cachedTableData = _xmlToTable(data);
        retrieveDataCallback(window.cachedTableData);
      };
   //INSTEAD OF THIS:
   //_basicAjaxRequest1(conData.xmlUrl, successCallback); 
   //USE NOT YQL BUT XMLHTTPREQUEST:
     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myFunction(this);
    }
 };
 xhttp.open('GET', 'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml', true);
 xhttp.send();

   return;
 }
 try {
   var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(conData.xmlString);
   window.cachedTableData = _xmlToTable(xmlDoc);
 }
 catch (e) {
   tableau.abortWithError("unable to parse xml data");
   return;
   }
 }
 retrieveDataCallback(window.cachedTableData);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get YQL work or comment on my approach trying to avoid it?

Thank you very much!

For reference, if there is any Tableau user that wants to test it on Tableau, here is my full code:

```
  <html>
   <head>
   <title>XML Connector</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="https://connectors.tableau.com/libs/tableauwdc-1.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

   (function() {
      var myConnector = tableau.makeConnector();
      myConnector.init = function () {
      tableau.connectionName = 'XML data';
      tableau.initCallback();
   };
   myConnector.getColumnHeaders = function() {
   _retrieveXmlData(function (tableData) {
   var headers = tableData.headers;
   var fieldNames = [];
   var fieldTypes = [];
   for (var fieldName in headers) {
     if (headers.hasOwnProperty(fieldName)) {
       fieldNames.push(fieldName);
       fieldTypes.push(headers[fieldName]);
     }
   }
   tableau.headersCallback(fieldNames, fieldTypes); // tell tableau about the fields and their types
   });
 }
  myConnector.getTableData = function (lastRecordToken) {
   _retrieveXmlData(function (tableData) {
     var rowData = tableData.rowData;
     tableau.dataCallback(rowData, rowData.length.toString(), false);
    });
 };
 tableau.registerConnector(myConnector);
 })();
function _retrieveXmlData(retrieveDataCallback) {
  if (!window.cachedTableData) {
    var conData = JSON.parse(tableau.connectionData);
    var xmlString = conData.xmlString;
   if (conData.xmlUrl) {
    var successCallback = function(data) {
    window.cachedTableData = _xmlToTable(data);
    retrieveDataCallback(window.cachedTableData);
   };
   //_basicAjaxRequest1(conData.xmlUrl, successCallback);
   //here try another approach not using yql but xmlHttpRequest?
   //try xml dom to get url (xml http request)
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myFunction(this);
    }
};
 xhttp.open('GET', 'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml', true);
 xhttp.send();    
     return;
}
try {
  var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(conData.xmlString);
  window.cachedTableData = _xmlToTable(xmlDoc);
}
catch (e) {
  tableau.abortWithError("unable to parse xml data");
  return;
  }
}
 retrieveDataCallback(window.cachedTableData);
}

function myFunction(xml) {  
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  window.cachedTableData = _xmlToTable(xmlDoc);
}

// There are a lot of ways to handle URLS. Sometimes we'll need workarounds for CORS. These
// methods chain together a series of attempts to get the data at the given url
 function _ajaxRequestHelper(url, successCallback, conUrl, nextFunction, 
   specialSuccessCallback){
   specialSuccessCallback = specialSuccessCallback || successCallback;
   var xhr = $.ajax({ 
      url: conUrl, 
      dataType: 'xml', 
      success: specialSuccessCallback,
      error: function()
    {
    nextFunction(url, successCallback);
    }
   });
  }

  // try the straightforward request
  function _basicAjaxRequest1(url, successCallback){
     _ajaxRequestHelper(url, successCallback, url, _yqlProxyAjaxRequest2);
  }

  // try to use yql as a proxy
  function _yqlProxyAjaxRequest2(url, successCallback){
     var yqlQueryBase = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";
     var query = "select * from htmlstring where url='" + url + "'";
     var restOfQueryString = "&format=xml" ;
     var yqlUrl = yqlQueryBase + encodeURIComponent(query) + restOfQueryString + "&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
    _ajaxRequestHelper(url, successCallback, yqlUrl, _giveUpOnUrl9);
  }

   function _giveUpOnUrl9(url, successCallback) {
      tableau.abortWithError("Could not load url: " + url);
   }

  // Takes a hierarchical xml document and tries to turn it into a table
  // Returns an object with headers and the row level data
  function _xmlToTable(xmlDocument) {
       var rowData = _flattenData(xmlDocument);
       var headers = _extractHeaders(rowData);
       return {"headers":headers, "rowData":rowData};
  }

  // Given an object:
  //   - finds the longest array in the xml
  //   - flattens each element in that array so it is a single element with many properties
  // If there is no array that is a descendent of the original object, this wraps
 function _flattenData(xmlDocument) {
     // first find the longest array
     var longestArray = _findLongestArray(xmlDocument, xmlDocument);
     if (!longestArray || longestArray.length == 0) {
        // if no array found, just wrap the entire object blob in an array
          longestArray = [objectBlob];
     }
     toRet = [];
     for (var ii = 0; ii < longestArray.childNodes.length; ++ii) {
     toRet[ii] = _flattenObject(longestArray.childNodes[ii]);
 }
  return toRet;
 }

 // Given an element with hierarchical properties, flattens it so all the properties
 // sit on the base element.
 function _flattenObject(xmlElt) {
    var toRet = {};
    if (xmlElt.attributes) {
       for (var attributeNum = 0; attributeNum < xmlElt.attributes.length; ++attributeNum) {
       var attribute = xmlElt.attributes[attributeNum];
       toRet[attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
     }
 }

 var children = xmlElt.childNodes;
 if (!children || !children.length) {
   if (xmlElt.textContent) {
   toRet.text = xmlElt.textContent.trim();
   }
 } else {  
for (var childNum = 0; childNum < children.length; ++childNum) {
  var child = xmlElt.childNodes[childNum];
  var childName = child.nodeName;
  var subObj = _flattenObject(child);
  for (var k in subObj) {
    if (subObj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        toRet[childName + '_' + k] = subObj[k];
    }
    }
}
  }
  return toRet;
 }

// Finds the longest array that is a descendent of the given object
 function _findLongestArray(xmlElement, bestSoFar) {
     var children = xmlElement.childNodes;
     if (children && children.length) {
     if (children.length > bestSoFar.childNodes.length) {
  bestSoFar = xmlElement;
}
for (var childNum in children) {
  var subBest = _findLongestArray(children[childNum], bestSoFar);
  if (subBest.childNodes.length > bestSoFar.childNodes.length) {
    bestSoFar = subBest;
   }
  }
}
return bestSoFar;
}
// Given an array of js objects, returns a map from data column name to data type
function _extractHeaders(rowData) {
  var toRet = {};
  for (var row = 0; row < rowData.length; ++row) {
  var rowLine = rowData[row];
  for (var key in rowLine) {
     if (rowLine.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       if (!(key in toRet)) {
        toRet[key] = _determineType(rowLine[key]);
       }
     }
   }
 }
  return toRet;
 }
// Given a primitive, tries to make a guess at the data type of the input
function _determineType(primitive) {
// possible types: 'float', 'date', 'datetime', 'bool', 'string', 'int'
  if (parseInt(primitive) == primitive) return 'int';
  if (parseFloat(primitive) == primitive) return 'float';
  if (isFinite(new Date(primitive).getTime())) return 'datetime';
  return 'string';
}
function _submitXMLToTableau(xmlString, xmlUrl) {
  var conData = {"xmlString" : xmlString, "xmlUrl": xmlUrl};
  tableau.connectionData = JSON.stringify(conData);
  tableau.submit();  
}
function _buildConnectionUrl(url) {
 // var yqlQueryBase = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";
 // var query = "select * from html where url='" + url + "'";
 // var restOfQueryString = "&format=xml";
 // var yqlUrl = yqlQueryBase + encodeURIComponent(query) + restOfQueryString;
 // return yqlUrl;
 return url;
 }
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var cancel = function (e) {    
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
  }
  $("#inputForm").submit(function(e) { // This event fires when a button is clicked
   // Since we use a form for input, make sure to stop the default form behavior
    cancel(e);
    var xmlString = $('textarea[name=xmlText]')[0].value.trim();
    var xmlUrl = $('input[name=xmlUrl]')[0].value.trim();
    _submitXMLToTableau(xmlString, xmlUrl);
 });
 var ddHandler = $("#dragandrophandler");
 ddHandler.on('dragenter', function (e) 
 {
   cancel(e);
   $(this).css('border', '2px solid #0B85A1');
 }).on('dragover', cancel)
   .on('drop', function (e) 
 {
   $(this).css('border', '2px dashed #0B85A1');
   e.preventDefault();
   var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
   var file = files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(e) { _submitXMLToTableau(reader.result); };
   reader.readAsText(file);
});
$(document).on('dragenter', cancel)
         .on('drop', cancel)
         .on('dragover', function (e) 
{
  cancel(e);
  ddHandler.css('border', '2px dashed #0B85A1');
 });
});
</script>

  <style>
    #dragandrophandler {
    border:1px dashed #999;
    width:300px;
    color:#333;
    text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;
    padding:10px 10px 10 10px;
    margin:10px;
     font-size:150%;
    }
  </style>
 </head>
<body>

<form id="inputForm" action="">
 Enter a URL for XML data: 
 <input type="text" name="xmlUrl" size="50" />  
 <br>
 <div id="dragandrophandler">Or Drag & Drop Files Here</div>
 <br>
 Or paste XML data below
 <br>
 <textarea name="xmlText" rows="10" cols="70"/></textarea>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```